# How can I make an image blurring app with a seekbar in android studio(giraffe)? Can't find an up to date tutorial

Tags: android, android-studio, blur, gaussianblur

I am trying to make an image blurring app, but can t figure it out.

I tried to implement a seekbar, by following a tutorial from 2020 but it is not working

the code is down below, since 2020 they modified android studio, so it is not working

```
package com.example.blurringapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.SeekBar
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.blurringapp.ui.theme.BLURRINGAPPTheme


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        var seekBar: SeekBar

            BLURRINGAPPTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background

            ) {
                Greeting("Android")
            }
        }
    }
}
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
Text(
    text = "Hello $name!",
    modifier = modifier
)
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
BLURRINGAPPTheme {
    Greeting("Android")
}
}
```

Where and how can I implement a seekbar?

Also how shoul I implement the image blurring?